# How can I treat a string as a sequence of hexadecimal values in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, char, hex, type-conversion, powershell-2.0

I have a string of characters in PowerShell like so:

`Encoded: A35C454A`

I want to treat each character as a hexadecimal value. In Ruby, this is as simple as `Encoded[0].hex`. How can I do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simples:

```
[Convert]::ToInt32($encoded[0], 16);
```

(**ToInt16** can be used too, but the built-in **Int** type is actually a shorthand for **Int32**)

Comment: Beautiful. This works with bitwise shifting now. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

please have a look

```
function asciiToHex($a)
{
$b = $a.ToCharArray();
Foreach ($element in $b) {$c = $c + "%#x" + [System.String]::Format("{0:X}",
[System.Convert]::ToUInt32($element)) + ";"}
$c
}
```

http://learningpcs.blogspot.in/2009/07/powershell-string-to-hex-or-whatever.html

Comment: This doesn't appear to do what the asker is trying to do, and you haven't explained the code at all so that point may not be clear to someone who doesn't already understand it.